# Updating a public application with different signer key

Tags: android, google-play, certificate

I have developed an app for quite a long time and now other developers work on it.
The app is published in Google Play store with **my signing certficate key**.

Thus they cannot publish updates because they have a different key.

My question is, can they update it, or if they cannot without my key, **is it safe to give them my certificate key?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They can't update it without the key.
2. It is not safe to give them your key unless you trust them utterly.

The simplest solution would be:

1. Ask them to send you a final build.
2. Verify build is ok.
3. Sign the build with your key.
4. Send the build back to them.
5. They can update the app with the build you sent back to them, but NOT with any other one. You are safe.

You can automate that process with script/build server if you wish in future.

Comment: So you mean i can directly sign an APK they send to me? Signing can be accomplish AFTER building?

Comment: Yes, you can sign an apt AFTER the build. You can check how to do that here - https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html